# event listener are attached but not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I have a React project in which there is a parent with  `'height: 100vh overflow:hidden'` having `id:parent_div`. In that parent a child component `ContentSection` is called that has `height:100vh overflow:auto`.

`ContentSection` maps the data and calls `UserFile` component:

```js
files.map((file)=>{return <Userfileentry/>})
```

`UserFile` renders the data on the Dom. It has a `useref: dropdown`. In this file, I am adding an event listener. Here's the code sample for that function:

```js
function adjust() {
  console.log('here')
  let elem = document.getElementById('parent_div').getClientBoundingRect()
  let dropdownrect = dropdown.current.getClientBoundingRect()
  if (elem.top < dropdownrect.top) {
    console.log('lesser')
  }
}
document.addEventListener('resize', adjust)
```

This adjust function is called on button click event and it works. However, the eventlistener is not triggered. When I inspect it, then the `Eventlistener` is attached there.

Similarly in `ContentSection`, I have attached:

```js
document.getElementById('parent_div').addEventListener('scroll',test)
```

And that is also not working. I have used the Ref to the 'parent_div' also and the element is successfully retrieved in `useEffect` but `Eventlistener` is not triggered.

Update:

(Codebox sample)https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-currying-odkogg?file=/src/UserFileEntry.js

I have added the link, here in the file userfileentry.js, there is line 50 which is not working in codesandbox so commented it. But, as you can see the above line is not working

Comment: Very hard to understand the problem, can you make a running example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-currying-odkogg?file=/src/UserFileEntry.js

Comment: I have added the link, here in the file userfileentry.js, there is line 50 which is not working in codesandbox so commented it. But, as you can see the above line is not working

Comment: @Twinkle I can't find your element with id `parent_div`? Also you are trying to access it wrongly: before JSX has rendered, you'd wanna use it in an `useEffect` with an empty dependency so that it runs *after* component has mounted. However even that doesn't work since your code doesn't have that id.

Comment: in App.js there it is present. and even if we ignore it. document.resize is not even working

Comment: You can't access `id` from another component's JSX. And i'm not sure where is *document.resize* I guess the `resize` event (*you shouldn't refer to it as 'document.resize'*) but adding more "*ignore it, even that other is not working*" won't work towards fixing the main issue.

Comment: @Twinkle Now is the time to read: [solving prop drilling react apps](https://blog.logrocket.com/solving-prop-drilling-react-apps). A wrong workaround for accessing `parent_div` id - an element 4 levels above `UserFileEntry` - is to use `useRef` hook inside your `App` and pass it down as prop, however I'd leave at suggesting you to not do that and follow the article above. Giving you an answer with props drilling where 3 components doesn't use it is like telling you to drive a car with 3 wheels, it would move..., that's against my will. Please refactor your code instead :)